# Apache kafka producer broker connection falls back to localhost

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm a kafka newb using the librdkafka c++ api - a single KafkaProducer instance sending records on several threads.  I was surprised to see that even though i specified a broker otherhost:port target, kafka tried to connect to localhost:

```log
[2024-03-07 09:11:16.172299]NOTICE KafkaProducer[22e68b0f-4efedb70] initializes with properties[batch.num.messages=1000|bootstrap.servers=192.168.68.111:29092|client.id=22e68b0f-4efedb70|enable.idempotence=true|enable.manual.events.poll=true|log_level=5|message.timeout.ms=15000]
...
%3|1709831480.173|FAIL|22e68b0f-4efedb70#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:29092/1]: localhost:29092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:29092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1709831480.364|ERROR|22e68b0f-4efedb70#producer-1| [thrd:app]: 22e68b0f-4efedb70#producer-1: localhost:29092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:29092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1709831480.444|FAIL|22e68b0f-4efedb70#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:29092/1]: localhost:29092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:29092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1709831480.686|ERROR|22e68b0f-4efedb70#producer-1| [thrd:app]: 22e68b0f-4efedb70#producer-1: localhost:29092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:29092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

no idea why this might be happening, help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap server address is only used for finding the servers, not sending/consuming data.

Please check your `advertised.listeners` setting in the broker `server.properties`.  This defaults to `localhost:9092`, and is what the server(s) will return to clients after an initial successful connection.